# Node.js: How Do I Pass A Vector To A Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-defined-functions

Here's my problem. Given that I am saving data in an array:

```
fetch.on('message', function(msg) {
        msg.data = '';
        msg.on('data', function(chunk) {
            msg.data += chunk;
        });
        msg.on('end', function() {
            msgCache[msg.id].body = msg.data;
        });
    });
fetch.on('end', function() {
     console.log('Done fetching bodies!');
     cb(undefined, msgCache);

  });
```

And:

```
fetch.on('end', function() {
       console.log('Done fetching bodies!');
       cb(undefined, msgCache, msg.id);
 });
```

Which sends the "msgCache" array to cb().

```
function(msgs) {
    console.log(msgs);  
}
```

Which works fine. However, I don't know how to get the msgs[msg.id] in the function and without that it's kind of useless to pass the array.

Is there a way I can access msgs[msg.id] in the last function?

Thanks

Output of console.log(msgs):

```
{ '9991': 
   { headers: 
      { date: [Object],
        to: [Object],
        from: [Object],
        subject: [Object] },
     body: 'test' },
  '9993': 
   { headers: 
      { date: [Object],
        to: [Object],
        from: [Object],
        subject: [Object] },
     body: 'teste2' } }
```

In order for this to work, I need to access msgs[9991].body for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you call `cb(undefined, msgCache, msg.id);` with right `msg.id` (in's not clear where you define it) then you can declare your `cb` function like this

`function cb(dunnowhat, msgs, id) {...}`

or i don't get it.

If your haven't `msg.id` then maybe `for .. in` helps

```
function cb(dunnowhat, msgs) {
  for (id in msgs) {
    console.log(msgs[id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. i'm passing a lot of messages, not only one. I've edited the question with the result of "msgs" in case of 2 messages.

Comment: I don't have "msg.id" when I call cb(). I've updated the code.